# Linq u getting slow

Tags: linq

i make a linq query matching two table primary key group by and mapped product only but getting slow

```
int mappedCount = (from product in products
                                   from productMapping in DbContext.ProductCategoryMappings where product.TenantId.Equals(productMapping.TenantId.ToString())
                                   && product.ProductGuid.ToUpper().Equals(productMapping.ProductId.ToString().ToUpper())
                                   from tenantCustMapping in DbContext.TenantCustCategories
                                   where tenantCustMapping.Id.Equals(productMapping.Value)
                                   select 1).ToList().Sum();
```

Product mapped invoceindex as 1 and finaly sum of mapped count

Comment: Is `products` also in your database? Is there a `DbContext.Products`?

Comment: DbContext.Products